# Сторонняя страница авторизации для HotSpot Mikrotik

Tags: mikrotik, hotspot, routeros

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующее:

Имеется MikroTik с настроенным HotSpot для гостей, режим Trial, то есть по умолчанию при нажатии на кнопку Trial пользователь сразу подключается к интернету. Но задача стояла чтобы пользователь вводил меняющийся ежедневно пароль.
Это реализовал с помощью Php, но Mikrotik не выполняет PHP.

И вопрос, как сделать авторизацию на стороннем хостинге или как реализовать систему паролей?

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если к триалу добавляем этот одноразовый пароль, то реализация должна выглядеть так:

В профиле хотспота указываешь папку `flash/default`

Качаешь папку html с микротика. Там иправляй форму входа: action ставь на свой сайт. Добавь поле с паролем и скрытые поля со значениями

```
$(link-login-only)
$(link-orig-esc)
$(mac-esc)
```

Твой пхп проверяет пароль и делает редирект на `$(link-login-only)?dst=$(link-orig-esc)&username=T-$(mac-esc)` при правильном пароле и `$(link-login-only)?dst=$(link-orig-esc)` при неправильном.

Закачивай папку на микротик обратно.